# Memory-block analysis - 3d program terminated unexpectedly

Tags: memory, data-structures, 3d, agk-basic

I try to put a mesh into virtual reality.

What I try to use is this command: [CreateObjectFromMeshMemblock](https://www.appgamekit.com/documentation/Reference/Memblock/CreateObjectFromMeshMemblock.htm)

The Data I insert is this data:

```
Byte No  Value
0        3     vertice count (aka first)
1        0     vertice count
2        0     vertice count
3        0     vertice count
4        3     indices count (aka second)
5        0     indices count
6        0     indices count
7        0     indices count
8        2     attr count    (aka third)
9        0     attr count
10       0     attr count
11       0     attr count
12       20    vertex size (aka fourth)
13       0     vertex size (20 because x+y+z + uvx+uvy = 5 * 4bytes = 20)
14       0     vertex size
15       0     vertex size
16       48    vertex-data offset (aka fifth)
17       0     vertex-data offset
18       0     vertex-data offset
19       0     vertex-data offset
20       108   indices-data offset (aka sixth)
21       0     indices-data offset
22       0     indices-data offset
23       0     indices-data offset
-- header success, starting vertex attribute data --
24       0     data type
25       3     cmp count
26       0     normalize flag
27       12    string length
28       112   p
29       111   o
30       115   s
31       105   i
32       116   t
33       105   i
34       111   o
35       110   n
36       0     \0
37       0     \0
38       0     \0
39       0     \0
40       1     data type
41       2     cmp count
42       0     normalize flag
43       4     string length
44       117   u 
45       118   v
46       0     \0
47       0     \0
-- offset vertex data --
48       0
49       0
50       183
51       66

52       0
53       0
54       183
55       66

56       0
57       0
58       183
59       66

60       0
61       0
62       0
63       0

64       0
65       0
66       0
67       0
 -- next vertex --
68       0
69       0
70       183
71       189

72       0
73       0
74       183
75       66

76       0
77       0
78       183
79       66

80       0
81       0
82       0
83       0

84       0
85       0
86       0
87       0
-- next vertex --
88       0
89       0
90       183
91       189

92       0
93       0
94       183
95       189

96       0
97       0
98       183
99       66

100      0
101      0
102      0
103      0

104      0
105      0
106      0 
107      0 
            -- now starting indices --
108      0 first index 
109      0 first index 
110      0 first index
111      0 first index
112      1 second index
113      0 second index
114      0 second index
115      0 second index 
116      2 third index
117      0 third index
118      0 third index
119      0 third index
```

Unfortuantely the program killing with errorcode 1 executing the command.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By analyzing your data it seems you're doing:

```
SetMemblockInt(memblock,0,3) //3 vertices
SetMemblockInt(memblock,4,3) //3 indices
SetMemblockint(memblock,8,2) //2 attributes, pos+uv
SetMemblockInt(memblock,12,20) // number bytes per vertex
SetMemblockInt(memblock,16,48) // vertex-data offset
SetMemblockInt(memblock,20,108) // indices-data offset
```

to setup your header, then:

```
SetMemBlockInt(memblock,24,0x0C000300) // float, 3 components, no normalizing, position
SetMemblockString(memblock,28,"position")

SetMemBlockInt(memblock,40,0x04000201) // unsigned byte, 2 components, no normalizing, uv
SetMemblockString(memblock,44,"uv")
```

to setup your attribute information and finally dumping both the vertex/index data, where you use offsets `48`, `108`. It seems the offsets of the whole dump are correct (if I'm my reviewing didn't miss anything) so I'm going to guess here:

- You're using `unsigned byte` as datatype for the uv coordinates instead `float`, maybe that's a mistake?
- The positions of your vertices are really suspicious and maybe your for loop is using wrong offsets/memory locations?

This is just guessing and by looking just at the memory dump isn't easy to find the bug, maybe if you posted the actual code I could make better assumptions

EDIT: It seems you're enforced to use the correct datatypes for the vertex attributes, a good hint is by considering the return types of the [Mesh](https://www.appgamekit.com/documentation/Reference/Memblock.htm) getters, ie:

```
float GetMeshMemblockVertexNormalX( memID, vertexIndex )
float GetMeshMemblockVertexNormalY( memID, vertexIndex )
float GetMeshMemblockVertexNormalZ( memID, vertexIndex )

float GetMeshMemblockVertexU( memID, vertexIndex )
float GetMeshMemblockVertexV( memID, vertexIndex )

float GetMeshMemblockVertexX( memID, vertexIndex )
float GetMeshMemblockVertexY( memID, vertexIndex )
float GetMeshMemblockVertexZ( memID, vertexIndex )

integer GetMeshMemblockVertexAlpha( memID, vertexIndex )
integer GetMeshMemblockVertexBlue( memID, vertexIndex )
integer GetMeshMemblockVertexGreen( memID, vertexIndex )
integer GetMeshMemblockVertexRed( memID, vertexIndex )
```

Also, make sure you use the [Error](https://www.appgamekit.com/documentation/Reference/Error.htm) functions to know more about the type of errors you're getting

Comment: uv coordinates are x and y on an image. image coordinates are alwals integers. but documentation sais everything except color is float. I think documentation is wrong here. But I will check this.

Comment: I read https://www.appgamekit.com/documentation/Reference/Memblock/GetMeshMemblockVertexU.htm and could confirm that it must be a float value.

Comment: Cool, so, was my guessing right? Was that the reason you were getting `errorcode 1` ?

Comment: Yes and yes!._.

Comment: Glad my guess was right, I've got lucky ;) . Edited slightly my answer